# Having Issue on Targeting Closest Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me konw why I am not able to target the closets `.inp2`

```js
$('.inp-1').focusout(function() {
  $(this).closest(".inp-2").css({"background": "green", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.inp-2{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="inp-1" id=""  placeholder="" /> Input 1
<input type="text" class="inp-2" id=""  placeholder="" /> Input 2
</div>

<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="inp-1" id=""  placeholder="" /> Input 1
<input type="text" class="inp-2" id=""  placeholder="" /> Input 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** instead, because **[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** is looking up the `DOM`:

```
$('.inp-1').focusout(function() {
   $(this).next(".inp-2").css({
     "background": "green",
     "border": "2px solid red"
   });
 });
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
 $('.inp-1').focusout(function() {
   $(this).next(".inp-2").css({
     "background": "green",
     "border": "2px solid red"
   });
 });
```

```css
.inp-2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="inp-1" id="" placeholder="" />Input 1
  <input type="text" class="inp-2" id="" placeholder="" />Input 2
</div>

<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="inp-1" id="" placeholder="" />Input 1
  <input type="text" class="inp-2" id="" placeholder="" />Input 2
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks itsgoingdown , I also got one question here , what if the inputs were wrapped in two different `<td`> of table? is the `.next()`  still works?

Comment: If I'm getting that `html` right, then it would be: `$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.inp-2').css(...)`